# How to clear the Vaadin CSS cache?

Tags: css, caching, vaadin, microsoft-edge, vaadin-flow

I just want to optimize the width of the drawer in Applayout for 2 different roles in our applications. I have the correct CSS to do this, but the development time takes too long, because the Vaadin CSS cache is not cleared. I am using Vaadin 14 and can not update,because of the system.

I am clearing the web history from Edge and Chrome in the correct way,
but the only way I have to clear the Vaadin CSS cache is to build a new WAR file and deploy on our server. This process takes to long time. So how can I locally (in my development environment) clear the Vaadin CSS cache?

Comment: What version of Vaadin are we talking? Flow for a very long time has warm-reload of of all JS/TS and CSS files (at least for the local frontend parts) and saving a file in your IDE would re-transpile and re-load your browser page automatically.

Comment: The version is Vaadin 14.

Comment: This warm-reload has no effect here. Is there some other way to clear the cache? Maybe running Maven site or depoy?

Comment: So why would it not work? Is the CSS in another module of your build? Does it work if you rebuild the module so the dev-tooling of the running app works? I think there is some puzzle pieace missing. Are you running your dev-env also in production mode?

Comment: The CSS is in the same module. I don't understand the question about "rebuild so the dev-tooling of the running app works". It was set to <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
,but I changed this to false. But it is the same issue again, CSS changes do not have any effect unless I deploy a new WAR file.